# Keyboard not working after wake up form suspend on HP Probook 6550b

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, suspend, 20.04, hp

So I have had this problem for a while that when I put my laptop to sleep, the keyboard then doesn't work. My external USB mouse works and my touchpad is disabled (so not an option). Please guide me to troubleshoot this.
P.S: I am a newbie to Linux so might need some detailed instructions.
HP Probook 6550b
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Problem was also present on 18.04 LTS)